# switch controllers within one tab bar item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What I want to do is to have my table view controller appear when the user presses a tab bar item, and when the user presses a cell in the table I want to switch to a nav controller while retaining the tab bar controller.

So far I've been testing my table view in my tab bar controller with a test UIViewController class and trying to switch to that.

I've added the following to my table view delegate method:

```
test *newTest = [[test alloc] init];
[self.view insertSubview:newTest.view atIndex:0];
```

It just overlaps the nib onto what I already have. I suspect I must clear my existing table view? Also, can I use this method with a UINavigationController?

I would like to add that initially I had a navigation controller with the table controllers within. However, the first table controller I did not want the top navigation bar. I only wanted a top bar until the person drilled down to the second level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your table VC back in your navigation stack as the root controller, but add these lines to have the navigation bar hide:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
  /* ...your existing code... */
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
  /* ...your existing code... */
}
```

You may need to put one or the other of these in the `viewDidAppear:`/`viewDidDisappear:` methods if the animation looks awkward or happens at the wrong time.

Also, as far as showing/hiding the tab bar goes, check out the [`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) field on `UIViewController`.

Comment: thanks. But when you drill down to the next level where I do want the nav bar, the nav bar appears in the first level while the animation "slide" is occurring. I guess there is no way to differentiate the two levels because there's only one nav controller

Comment: I solved it by adding the [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated]; to the class of the second level rather than the delegate of the first level. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

QUick Solution: Load your View Controller on the click(tabBar Item). Navigate within the view controller for loading another view on selecting cell.

```
Methods that can be used:


 tabBarController.viewControllers=/*Array of ViewControllers*/
  [tabBarController.theTabBar setHidden:YES]; //Use it if you want to hide from anywhere in your program
 tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath://for loading another view on selecting cell
```